# How can I most effectively parse this HTTP request in C?

Tags: c, string, http, parsing

The information I really need to extract is:

a) Whether or not it is a `GET` request

b) The file address (e.g. index.html)

c) The host information (e.g. localhost:8081)

I have code to do this just now (see bottom of my post), but it seems inefficient, quite static, and doesn't pull the host information.

So I'd like to have a *sane* solution to parsing the HTTP request in C. Cheers!

**HTTP Request**

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.70 Safari/537.17
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

**Current Code**

```
int parsehttp(char *inputstring, int *type, char *getaddress) {
    if((strncmp(inputstring, "GET", 3)) == 0) {
        *type = 1;
    } else {
        *type = 0;
    }
    char firstline[BUFLEN] = "";
    int charoffset = getlineend(inputstring); //this function returns the int offset of '\r\n'
    strncpy(firstline, inputstring, charoffset-2);
    firstline[charoffset-1] = '\0';
    sscanf(firstline,"%*s %s %*s",getaddress);
    inputstring = (inputstring + charoffset);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd say you're looking for a regexp, regular expression. Look up some tutorials and that shouldn't be a big problem :)

Comment: @dutt If he tries this with regexp then he will have **2** problems.

Comment: A sane solution in parsing data coming from the internet includes checks for buffer overflows and all kinds of other validations.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: A sane solution to any problem includes checks for buffer overflows and all kinds of other validations. :)

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, you might like to read here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Comment: This can be accomplish with `strtok_r()` and `strncmp()`. https://github.com/MaG21/linux-http-proxy/blob/master/http.c look at the `http_parse_request()` (a source code I'm working on), it may give you a hint or ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might help you, is the strstr-function. It tries to locate a given string in a string you provide. As an HTTP-request consists of a line ending in 0xD,0xA you can split the lines.
Usually information on a line of text is separated using whitespace.
So to find "GET" or "POST" you use

```
char* getpost = strstr("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", "GET");
```

If getpost is != NULL, you'll have your string and can cut it after either GET or POST.

Secondly you'll look for "Host: " and skipt that part until you reach 0xD,0xA so you got your host-address.

See [strstr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/) for the manpage on strstr.

Comment: you can easily get a buffer overrun with strstr - to be sane, you should use a strnstr implementation (or roll your own)

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about this being inefficient, it is networking after all and will always be many magnitudes slower than your CPU, cache, RAM.

If you are writing an http-server then the only thing you should care about is memory-safety and what your code does if the client sends something unexpected.

Some examples: 
What does your code (and the code that follows this / is dependent upon its parsing) do if:

- the client sends > 10 MB of data, all mal-formed, eg no line-breaks at all.
- the client sends wrong decimals (ie ip/port/content-length)
- the client sends correct data but malicously slowly, eg 1 byte per second.
- ... much much more.

Comment: I know because i just completed my own asynchronous web-server.

Comment: -1 I've also written webservers in the past and not worrying about CPU and/or RAM is a really bad idea. If you don't worry about those, just use Apache or some other slow server out there, and don't roll your own.